# Collect common denominator of sum

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I have a sum where each term shares the same denominator, e.g., `a/Z + b/Z + ...`. I want to factor out the `Z`. Although `simplify` can do it, it takes too long. I've tried `collect` and `factor`, but neither does what I want.

Is there a SymPy function that can be used for this?

Comment: would you mind to tell which terms you have, so that people can test?

Comment: Your question is too vague since you give so little detail about your sum. You also do not explain just how `simplify` is too slow. Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It would be very nice to have the actual sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `together`:

```
>>> together(x/z + y/z)
(x + y)/z
```

See [its docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.rationaltools.together) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand what you want, but perhaps `fraction` would be useful. For example:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, y = symbols('x y')
>>> f =  (x**2 + 1) / (2*y)
>>> (num, den) = fraction(f)
>>> den
2*y
```

Comment: `fraction` does not combine common denominators first, although `expr.as_numer_denom()` does.

Comment: @asmeurer My rationale was that if the denominators are all the same, then one only needs the denominator of the first fraction in the sum.